# XPath - Selecting elements that equal a value

Tags: xpath

In Xpath, I am wanting to select elements that equal a specific value.

Sample XML data:

```
<aaa id="11" >
    <aaa id="21" >
        <aaa id="31" ></aaa>
        <bbb id="32" >
            <aaa id="41" ></aaa>
            <bbb id="42" ></bbb>
            <ccc id="43" ></ccc>
            <ddd id="44" >qwerty</ddd>
            <ddd id="45" ></ddd>
            <ddd id="46" ></ddd>
        </bbb>
    </aaa>
    <bbb id="22" >
         <aaa id="33" >qwerty</aaa>
         <bbb id="34" ></bbb>
         <ccc id="35" ></ccc>
         <ddd id="36" ></ddd>
         <ddd id="37" ></ddd>
         <ddd id="38" ></ddd>
    </bbb>
    <ccc id="23" >qwerty</ccc>
    <ccc id="24" ></ccc>
 </aaa>
```

Now, using the XPath:

```
//ccc[.='qwerty']
```

I get the correct, *expected* results:

```
Name    Value
ccc     qwerty
```

Now, using the XPath:

```
//aaa[.='qwerty']
```

I get *unexpected* results:

```
Name    Value
aaa      
aaa     qwerty
```

**And what I am particularly interested, is how to select *any* element with that value**

XPath:

```
//*[.='qwerty']
```

I get very strange *unexpected* results:

```
Name    Value
aaa
bbb
ddd     qwerty
bbb     qwerty
aaa     qwerty
ccc     qwerty
```

Can someone explain these results, and how to fix my XPath expressions to get more expected results?

Comment: Because XPath `. =` is different than XPath `text() =`.  See [**matching text nodes is different than matching string values**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34595441/290085) to learn why.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

**The XPath spec. defines the *string value* of an element as the concatenation (in document order) of all of its text-node descendents**.

This explains the "strange results".

"Better" results can be obtained using the expressions below:

```
//*[text() = 'qwerty']
```

The above selects every element in the document that has at least one text-node child with value 'qwerty'.

```
//*[text() = 'qwerty' and not(text()[2])]
```

The above selects every element in the document that has only one text-node child and its value is: 'qwerty'.

Comment: @iHeartGreek: Glad it works. How about accepting / upvoting ? `text()` is one of the possible *node-tests* in XPath, meaning "is this a text node?". Other nodetests are `comment()`, `processing-instruction()`, or just `node()`.

Answer (score 19):

Try

`//*[text()='qwerty']` because `.` is your *current* element

Answer (score 2):

Better use `//*[normalize-space(text()) = 'qwerty']` . If there are any whitespaces around the text, they will be removed.