# Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have a node as follows:

```
<span class="portal-text-medium">Office Hours</span>
```

For the XPath I use

```
//span[text()='Office Hours']
```

which should work, but it never does.  I can use `*contains(text(),'Office Hours')]*` but that won't find an exact match and I have to verify there is no "*".  This is not the only time it hasn't worked for me.  I have seen it work before so I don't know what is wrong.  Any idea?

Yes I can, and do, use `starts-with` but it is not quite the same.

Comment: I have the page open in Chrome, and I do an inspect and then ctrl-f which opens a box in the lower left corner into which I can type xpaths.  If the xpath matches, then the number of matches is shown and the first one is highlighted in yellow.  Actually even if no match is found the number of matches is shown, and is shown as 0.  When I use this xpath 0 matches are shown.  When I use contains() or starts-with(), 14 or so matches are shown.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### XPath `text() =` is different than XPath `. =`

***(Matching text nodes is different than matching string values)***

The following XPaths are ***not*** the same...

1. `//span[text() = 'Office Hours']`

   **Says**:

   *Select the `span` elements that
   have an **immediate** child* [text node](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Text-Nodes) *equal to 'Office Hours`.*
2. `//span[. = 'Office Hours']`

   **Says**:

   *Select the `span` elements whose* [string value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) *is equal to 'Office Hours`*.

**In short, for [element nodes](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#element-nodes):**

> The [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of an element node is the concatenation of the
>   [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value)s of all text node [descendants](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-descendants) of the element
>   node in document order.

### Examples

The following `span` elements ***would match  only #1***:

- `<span class="portal-text-medium">Office Hours<br/>8:00-10:00</span>`
- `<span class="portal-text-medium">My<br/>Office Hours</span>`

The following `span` elements ***would match only #2***:

- `<span class="portal-text-medium"><b>Office</b> Hours</span>`
- `<span class="portal-text-medium"><b><i>Office Hours</i></b></span>`

The following `span` element ***would match both #1 and #2***:

- `<span class="portal-text-medium">Office Hours</span>`

Comment: So for using a ".", parts of the string can be at different depths, as long as when appended together it comes out to the value you are searching?

I think sometimes when I encountered that problem I should have tried I should have used a . because maybe there were some extra levels I did not know about.

Comment: You got it.  More precisely per the XPath recommendation:  *The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order.*  Answer updated.  Thanks.

Comment: A relevant quote from the [XPath Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans): _"If one object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a string, then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the string-value of the node and the other string is true."_