# XPath: Way to match text inside an arbitrary number of nested elements?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Is it possible for one XPath expression to match all the following `<a>` elements using the text in the element, in this case `"Link"`?

**Examples:**

1. `<a href="blah">Link</a>`
2. `<a href="blah"><span>Link</span></a>`
3. `<a href="blah"><div>Link</div></a>`
4. `<a href="blah"><div><span>Link</span></div></a>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This simple XPath expression,

```
//a[contains(., 'Link')]
```

will select the `a` elements of all of your examples because `.` represents the current node (`a`), and `contains()` will check the [***string value***](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) of `a` to see if it contains `'Link'`.  The string value of `a` already conveniently abstracts away from any descendent elements.

This even simpler XPath expression,

```
//a[. = 'Link']
```

will also select the `a` elements in all of your examples.  It's appropriate to use if the string value of `a` will exactly equal, rather than just contain, `"Link"`.

**Note**: The above expressions will also select `<a href="blah">Li<br/>nk</a>`, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: +1 - I was originally going to post `//a[contains(., 'Link')]`, but it doesn't strictly match text because as you pointed out, it would match `<a>Li<br/>nk</a>` and `<a><span>L</span>ink</a>` so it's safer to use `text()` in my opinion...

Comment: @JoshCrozier, thanks, and your answer is very useful too (+1), but safest is really for OP to understand how these variations work so he can chose what he intends.  Also, note that ***[XPath `text() =` is different than XPath `. =`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34595441/290085)***

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following:

```
//a[(.//*|.)[contains(text(), "Link")]]
```

This will select `a` elements that contain the text "Link" or `a` elements that have a descendant element that contains the text "Link".

- `//a` - Select all `a` elements
- `(` - Open OR grouping
- `.//*` Select all the descendant nodes
- `|` - Or..
- `.` - Select the current node
- `)` -  Close OR grouping
- `[contains(text(), "Link")]` - If they contain the text "Link"

Alternatively, you could also use:

```
//a[(.//*|.)[.="Link"]]
```

Comment: Hmmm, tried the first suggestion and no match was found. The second suggestion found a different link in the document other than the one I wanted. There is only on hyperlink on the page with the text "Link" so not sure how that happened.

Comment: OK, I took a wild guess and threw parentheses around the "or" expression. That did the trick. Thanks for your help!

`//a[(.//*|.)[text() = \"$text\"]]`