# XPath locating element using text() not working

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

```
<td>
 <a>SAMPLE</a>
 <div>
  <small>Phase:
         Planning >>
  <a>Performance</a>
  </small>
 </div>         
</td>
```

I'm trying to locate the element with "Phase: Planning >> Performance" text on the above but to no avail.

Tried using :

```
//*[text()[contains(normalize-space(.),'Phase: Planning >> Performance')]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***None of the currently existing other three answers will do exactly what you ask.***

Here are some XPath expressions that will:

- You can select the ***`small` elements*** whose normalized string
  value is `Phase: Planning >> Performance` via this XPath:

  ```
  //small[normalize-space() = 'Phase: Planning >> Performance']
  ```
- You can select ***all elements, regardless of name*** whose
  normalized string values equals the targeted string:

  ```
  //*[normalize-space() = 'Phase: Planning >> Performance']
  ```

  but this will select not only `small` but also `div` because both
  have a string value equal to `Phase: Planning >> Performance`.
- You can select **only the lowest element in the hierarchy, regardless
  of name**  whose normalized string values equals the targeted string:

  ```
  //*[         normalize-space() = 'Phase: Planning >> Performance' and 
      not(.//*[normalize-space() = 'Phase: Planning >> Performance'])]
  ```

---

It is important to realize that **[XPath text() = is different than XPath . =](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34595441/290085)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below:-

```
//small[contains(.,'Phase:')]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span>Planning &gt;&gt;</span>
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

The text `Phase: Planning >>` and `Performance` belongs to two different elements.

To locate `Phase: Planning >>` element you can use

```
//small[contains(text(),'Phase:')]
```

And to locate the `Performance` element

```
//a[contains(text(),'Performance')]
```

Note that that printing the first element will give you the text of both elements `Phase: Planning >> Performance`.