# Why won't my XPath select link/button based on its label text?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="home">
    <span class="menu_icon">Maybe more text here</span>
    Home
</a>
```

So for above code when I write `//a` as XPath, it gets highlighted, but when I write `//a[contains(text(), 'Home')]`, it is not getting highlighted. I think this is simple and should have worked.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: Is it's text the **only** thing you can match on? It will be pretty unstable.

Comment: Above xpath was working well earlier, I don't know why it is not working now. Though developer mentioned there is some changes done in html at parent label but this part of code seems to be same, so I think the code could have worked. Since similar code is written at other place I wanted to avoid changing xpath again for similar elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Other answers have missed the actual problem here:**

1. Yes, you could match on `@title` instead, but that's not why OP's
   XPath is failing where it may have worked previously.
2. Yes, XML and XPath are case sensitive, so `Home` is not the same as
   `home`, but there is a `Home` text node as a child of `a`, so OP is
   right to use `Home` if he doesn't trust `@title` to be present.

---

### Real Problem

OP's XPath,

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Home')]
```

says to select all `a` elements whose first text node contains the substring `Home`.  Yet, the first text node contains nothing but whitespace.

**Explanation:** `text()` selects all child text nodes of the context node, `a`.  When `contains()` is given multiple nodes as its first argument, it takes the string value of the ***first*** node, but `Home` appears in the second text node, not the first.

Instead, OP should use this XPath,

```
//a[text()[contains(., 'Home')]]
```

which says to select all `a` elements with ***any*** text child whose string value contains the substring `Home`.

If there weren't surrounding whitespace, this XPath could be used to test for equality rather than substring containment:

```
//a[text()[.='Home']]
```

Or, with surrounding whitespace, this XPath could be used to trim it away:

```
//a[text()[normalize-space()= 'Home']]
```

---

### See also:

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath/34595441#34595441)
- [Why is XPath unclean constructed? Why is text() not needed in predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195275/why-is-xpath-unclean-constructed-why-is-text-not-needed-in-predicate/38208411#38208411)
- [XPath: difference between dot and text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this XPath..Its just select element by attribute

```
 //a[@title,'home']
```

Comment: I know it will work in this case, but earlier I had written the xpath which I mentioned above which worked well, I don't know why it is not working now. Though developer mentioned there is some changes done in html at parent label but still I think the code could have worked

Comment: I am not sure but your text home inside invited commas "Home" It can be a reason.

Comment: Tried giving with double quotes but didn't worked //a[contains(text(),'"Home"')] or //a[contains(text(),""Home"")] or //a[contains(text(),"""Home""")] not working

Comment: Suppose I have text like  "WE'd like to hear from you"

Then Xpath will be something like //input[contains(@text,\"WE'd\"]

Hope in this way you can solve your problem

Comment: Helpful (+1) but [***something more subtle is causing OP's problem***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46488908/290085).

Answer (score 1):

yes you are doing 2 mistakes, you're writing `Home` with an uppercase H when you want to match `home` with a lowercase h. also you're trying to check the text content, when you want to check check the "title" attribute. correct those 2, and you get:

```
//a[contains(@title, 'home')]
```

however, if you want to match the exact string `home`, instead of any a that has `home` anywhere in the title attribute, use @zsbappa's code.

Comment: Helpful (+1) but [***something more subtle is causing OP's problem***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46488908/290085).