# Selecting elements based on string/text matching in XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

For HTML tables on web page I am using the following XPath:

```
/tr/td[2]/.[contains(text(),'Some')]
```

This works fine in all the case but it also match 'Something'.

```
/tr/td[2]/.[normalize-space(text()) = 'Some']
```

doesn't work in all the cases.
Can somebody comment on what's wrong with latter XPath?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the latter path. Please provide an example of HTML code where the given XPath doesn't work as you'd expect.  Otherwise it's hardly possible to help you.

Comment: @ThomasW: Actually, both XPath's are malformed:  Probably OP meant to use `*` rather than `.`.   But beyond that, I agree that the problem is probably not about `normalize-space()`.   See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38253476/290085) for details.

Comment: @user2764578: Asking 12 questions over 2 years without accepting a single answer is a sign you should read [**How does accepting an answer work?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) and probably also  **[ask]**.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't likely involve `normalize-space()` but rather one of two common text/string matching areas of confusion:

### Text node vs string value

`text()` matches text nodes.

`//td[contains(text(), 'Some')]` will match this

```
<td>Some text</td>
```

but not

```
<td><b>Some text</b></td>
```

To match the latter too, use `//td[contains(., 'Some')]` instead.  This will check that the *string value* of `td` contains the string "Some".

For more details, see [***XPath text() = is different than XPath . =***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34595441/290085)

### String contains vs string equals

Note also that `contains()` tests for substring containment.  If you want string equality, use the `=` operator against string:

```
//td[. = 'Some']
```

Will match

```
<td><b>Some</b></td>
```

but not

```
<td><b>Some text</b></td>
```

Be aware of the difference.

Comment: I have <td>    Some    <span>..</span></td>  So I think '.' won't work here, I tried [normalize-space(text()) = 'Some'] ..but it's not working

Comment: Stop guessing and asking us to guess.  Provide a true [mcve], or Thomas W is right:  It's not possible to help you.