# XPath to get markup between two headings

Tags: html, xml, xpath, web, wikipedia

I am trying to write a small application to extract content from Wikipedia pages. When I first thought if it, I thought that I could just target divs containing content with XPath, but after looking into how Wikipedia builds their articles, I quickly discovered that wouldn't be so easy. The best way to separate content when I get the page, is to select what's between two sets of `h2` tags.

Example: 
`<h2>Title</h2> <div>Some Content</div> <h2>Title</h2>`

Here I would want to get the `div` between the sets of headers. I tried doing this with XPath, but with no luck at all. I am going to look more into XPath because I think that's what I need to use to achieve what I want, but before I look too much into it, I would like to hear what you guys think about it. Is XPath the right way to go or do I have other easier options? I write the application in C# if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you're on the right track with XPath -- it's ideal for selecting parts of an XML document.**

For example, for this XML,

```
<r>
   <h2>Title A</h2>
   <div>Some Content</div>
   <div>More Content</div>
   <h2>Title B</h2>
</r>
```

this XPath,

```
//div[preceding-sibling::h2 = 'Title A' and following-sibling::h2 = 'Title B']
```

will select this content,

```
<div>Some Content</div>
<div>More Content</div>
```

between the two `h2` titles, as requested.

---

**Update to address OP's self-answer:**

For this new XML example,

```
<div>
    <h2><span>Summary</span></h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <ul>
        <li>List1</li>
        <li>List2</li>
        <li>List3</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Paragraph</p>

    <h2><span>Location</span></h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

the XPath I provided above can easily be adapted,

```
//*[preceding-sibling::h2 = 'Summary' and following-sibling::h2 = 'Location']
```

to select this XML,

```
<p>Paragraph</p>  
<ul>
   <li>List1</li>
   <li>List2</li>
   <li>List3</li>
</ul>    
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

as requested.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you :-) I will mark as correct answer after I test it when I get home.

Comment: I added my own answer the correct answer. Your answer did guide me in the right direction though!

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.     (Not sure what you mean by *I added my own answer the correct answer*, unless you mean you had to make adjustments -- I don't see another SO answer posted here by you to this question.)

Comment: I just posted it now. Got distracted by a phonecall ^^

Comment: I'm glad you got it working on your own, however you might want to review my updated answer that works with your new sample; it's simpler and more robust than what you've posted in your answer.   You'll want to understand the [difference between testing text nodes and string values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34595441/290085), for example.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from kjhughes suggestion, I managed to get the code working.

I was unable to make the `= 'Text'` part work, but replaced it with `[text() = 'text']`

That alone wasn't enough, as the title of the content I need is location inside a `span` in a `h2` tag, so I had to adapt the XPath a bit more.

This is what I came up with:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::h2::following-sibling::span[text() = 'Summary'] and following-sibling::h2::following-sibling::span[text() = 'Location']]
```

I tested it using http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath on this HTML:

```
<div>
    <h2><span>Summary</span></h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <ul>
        <li>List1</li>
        <li>List2</li>
        <li>List3</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Paragraph</p>

    <h2><span>Location</span></h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Which gave me the following result:

```
<p>Paragraph</p>
<ul>
    <li>List1</li>
    <li>List2</li>
    <li>List3</li>
</ul>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```