# How do I get my XPath to search only within each table?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a bit of HTML that looks like this:

```
<table class="resultsTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="even">
            <td width="35%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
            <td>ACME ANVILS, INC</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and some C# code that looks like this:

```
var name = document.DocumentNode
                   .SelectSingleNode("//*[text()='Name']/following::td").InnerText
```

which happily returns

```
ACME ANVILS, INC.
```

However, there's a new wrinkle.  The page in question now returns multiple results:

```
<table class="resultsTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="even">
            <td width="35%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
            <td>ACME ANVILS, INC.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="resultsTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="even">
            <td width="35%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
            <td>ROAD RUNNER RACES, LLC</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So now I'm working with

```
var tables = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody");
foreach (var table in tables)
{
    var name = table.SelectSingleNode("//*[text()='Name']/following::td").InnerText;
    ...
}
```

Which falls over, because `SelectSingleNode` returns null.

How do I get my XPath to actually return a result, searching only within the specific table I have selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the addition of a second table, two adjustments are required:

1. Change your absolute XPath,

   ```
   //*[text()='Name']/following::td
   ```

   to one relative to the current `table` or `tbody` element:

   ```
   .//*[text()='Name']/following::td
   ```
2. Account for there now being more than one `td` element on the
   `following::` axis.

   Either just grab the first,

   ```
   (.//*[text()='Name']/following::td)[1]
   ```

   or, better, use the `following-sibling::` axis instead in combination
   with a test on the string value of `td` rather than a test on a text node, which might be buried beneath intervening formatting elements:

   ```
    .//td[.='Name']/following-sibling::td
   ```

   See also [Difference between Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath).