# XPath selector that can handle variable structures

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I have some text I need to extract using XPath selectors. The text can be in 3 different forms:

```
<td>
    TARGET_TEXT
</td>

<td>
    <p>
        TARGET_TEXT
    </p>
</td>

<td>
    <p>
        <strong>TARGET_TEXT</strong>
    </p>
</td>
```

Is there an XPath statement/selector I can use that will handle all 3 of these scenarios? Or is it possible to add `OR` statements in an XPath selector?

```
for tr in table_rows:
    # only handles case 1
    topic_name = tr.xpath('.//td[1]/text()').extract()[0]
```

Comment: Hey, Jake, how about [**accepting**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) some of the fine answers you've gotten in the past.  You've asked 18 questions since August and accepted 0.  Something's wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
normalize-space(/td)
```

will return the same space-normalized string value of `/td`,

```
TARGET_TEXT
```

for all three of your cases.

For more information on string values in XPath, see [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath).

Answer (score 0):

```
for tr in table_rows:

    all_three = tr.xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the following is adequate:

```
for tr in table_rows:
    topic_name = tr.xpath('.//td[1]//text()').extract()
    # topic_name can be ['\r\n', 'TARGET_TEXT', '\r\n']
    topic_name = ''.join(topic_name)
```