# Scrapy: How to get a correct selector

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I would like to select the following text:

**Bold** normal *Italics*

I need to select and get: Bold normal italist.

The html is:

```
<a href=""><strong>Bold</strong> normal <i>Italist</i></a>
```

However, `a/text()` yields

> normal

only. Does anyone know a fix? I'm testing bing crawling, and the bold text is in different position depending on the query.

Comment: You need to understand [**the difference between text nodes and string values in XPath**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41077106/290085)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `a//text()` instead of `a/text()` to get all text items.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.selector import Selector

doc = """
<a href=""><strong>Bold</strong> normal <i>Italist</i></a>
"""

sel = Selector(text=doc, type="html")

result = sel.xpath('//a/text()').extract()
print result
# >>> [u' normal ']

result = u''.join(sel.xpath('//a//text()').extract())
print result
# >>> Bold normal Italist
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use

```
a/string()
```

or

```
normalize-space(a)
```

which returns `Bold normal Italist`

Comment: Scrapy only supports XPath 1.0, so `a/string()` will not work.