# Cover two cases with single XPath?

Tags: java, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I want to find element with XPath in Selenium, which contain text, but has two possible cases. Here there are :

```
.//li/a[contains(., 'blah')]
.//li/a/span[contains(., 'blah')]
```

How to cover the two cases with single XPath?

Second question if possible I want to get as result pointer to the `a` element, not to the `span` in both cases.

Also, is there a general way to return as a match parent of the matched element, instead ?

Comment: Doesn't the first XPath `.//li/a[contains(., 'blah')]` cover both cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, XPaths expressions can be combined with `|` (eg: `xpath1 | xpath2`), however you don't really need to do so in this case...

As Josh Crozier asks in the comments, yes, `.//li/a[contains(., 'blah')]` covers both cases.

The string value of `a` necessarily will contain `"blah"` if any of its descendant `span` element's string values contain `"blah"`.

> Second question if possible I want to get as result pointer to the
>   a-element, not to the span in both cases.

`.//li/a[contains(., 'blah')]` will return such `a` elements.

Be aware that it will also return such `a` elements as

```
 <a>xxxblah</a>
 <a><span>blah</span></a>
 <a><span>bl</span><span>ah</span></a>
```

> PS> BTW is there a general way to return as a match parent of the
>   matched element, instead ?

Well, appending `/..` to an XPath will return the parent, but I suspect you'd benefit from learning about the string value of XML elements.  See [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath)

Answer (score 2):

You should test the xpath I'm giving you to make sure it doesn't return more matches than you want, but I'd just use: `//a[contains(.,'blah')]`

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this
.//li/*[contains(., 'blah')]