# XPath for selecting all text nodes

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath

I'm writing a JavaScript function that can be used to replace text with HTML code, but to do this I need to be able to access text in text node form. The following XPath selects all `div` tags in a document:

```
//div
```

The following XPath selects all elements with the attribute `class` assigned the value `myclass`:

```
//*[@class="myclass"]
```

The following selects all of the **text** (not text nodes) that occurs at any level underneath the element with the ID `comments`:

```
//*[@id="comments"]//text()
```

What is an XPath that can be used to select all text nodes under any element? So, say I want to replace all the non-comment occurrences of the string `Hebert` and I need all of the text nodes so I can scan through them for that string. Would it use `text()` in the query?

Comment: Element nodes have text nodes in it, that you can manipulate. Are you referring to Element nodes that only have text and no child Element nodes in it?

Comment: ***You really ought to [accept](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215)  some of the fine answers you've received to the 75 questions you've asked.***  Asking **75 questions and accepting 0 of the fine answers you've received** (and only ever upvoting twice in 4 years) shows a lack of appreciation for the help you've received and failure to help future readers.   It's not too late to fix this situation.  You should do so now.

Answer (score 9):

Two options:

- To select all text nodes whose string value *contains* the substring
  "Herbert":

  ```
  //text()[contains(.,'Herbert')]
  ```
- To select all text nodes whose string value *is* "Herbert":

  ```
  //text()[.='Herbert']
  ```

Note that your comment,

> The following selects all of the text (not text nodes)

regarding the XPath, `//text()`, is incorrect.  The node test [**`text()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Text-Nodes) selects text nodes.  In a string context, it will return the [***string-value***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) of the text node, but `text()` alone most certainly selects actual text nodes.

See also [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath)