# Possible to use following-sibling axis multiple times in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<div>
    <pre>
        <span class="attr">id:</span>
        <span class="text">1</span>
        <span class="attr">time:</span>
        <span class="text">42</span>
        <span class="attr">length:</span>
        <span class="text">74</span>

        <span class="attr">id:</span>
        <span class="text">2</span>
        <span class="attr">time:</span>
        <span class="text">57</span>
        <span class="attr">length:</span>
        <span class="text">74</span>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Here's a mockup of some HTML I'm working with. I'm trying to use XPATH to find the amount of time that is associated with id: 1, and only id: 1, not id: 2.

```
//span[@class = 'attr'][text()='id:']/following-sibling::span[1][text()='1']
```

correctly gets the '1' element for id for me, but my attempt to do

```
 //span[@class = 'attr'][text()='id:']/following-sibling::span[1][text()='1']/following-sibling::span[1][text()='time:']/following-sibling::span[1]
```

in order to grab the number after time after id: 1 doesn't work for me. I need the xpath to identify only the times after a certain id, so using a single following id after the time element won't work for me, as it also needs to find the id. Is it even possible to do following-sibling twice/thrice in a row? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sure, you can use `following-sibling::` multiple times.  I've tested your XPaths, and both work.  What do you mean by "won't work for me"?

Comment: Sorry, looks like that is indeed the case. On my real code was just confusing what number I should put after the last span. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `following-sibling::` axis multiple times.

Your XPath works as intended.  Given the layout of your HTML, there's not much you can do by way of shortening the XPath other than to perhaps use the string value of the `spans` rather than child `text()` nodes:

```
 //span[@class='attr'][.='id:']/following-sibling::span[1][.='1']
                               /following-sibling::span[1][.='time:']
                               /following-sibling::span[1]
```

Comment: Is there a difference between using [text()='1'] and [.='1'] other than the second being easier to write? Thanks

Comment: Yes, most definitely they are different in general, but in your case it won't matter.  To understand the differences, see [**XPath text() = is different than XPath . =**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)