# XPATH: Find piece of text anywhere in document

Tags: xml, xpath

Is there any way to just search the whole html document for a piece of text without worrying about tags, classes etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, something like this :

```
//text()[contains(.,'keyword')]
```

Or, use one of the following XPath if you prefer to return parent element where the target keyword resides :

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'keyword')]]
//text()[contains(.,'keyword')]/..
```

Comment: Only limitation with this is that the string must be contained in a single text node: so no internal markup.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
contains(/,'keyword')
```

will return true if `keyword` is contained anywhere in the string value of the document.

Note it could match substrings conjoined across elements (i.e. `<r>key<b>word</b></r>`), which may or may not be desirable.  If undesirable, see [@har07's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43996961/290085) (+1).

**See also:** [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath/34595441)