# XPath for a span based on its text?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to locate first span with XPath I tried:

```
//*[@id='student-grid']/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/span/span[contains(text(), 'Edit School')]
```

to select span with text - Edit Student button

```html
<tbody role="rowgroup">
<tr class="" data-uid="2f3646c6-213a-4e91-99f9-0fbaa5f7755d" role="row" aria-selected="false">
<td class="select-row" role="gridcell">
<td class="font-md" role="gridcell">marker, Lion</td>
<td role="gridcell">TESTLINK_1_ArchScenario</td>
<td role="gridcell">1st</td>
<td role="gridcell">Not Started</td>
<td role="gridcell"/>
<td role="gridcell"/>
<td role="gridcell">QA Automation TestLink Folders</td>
<td class="k-cell-action" role="gridcell"/>
<td class="k-cell-action detail-view-link font-md" role="gridcell">
<span class="button-grid-action kendo-lexia-tooltip icon-pencil" role="button" title="Edit Student">
<span>Edit Student</span>
</span>
</td>
<td class="k-cell-action archive-link font-md" role="gridcell">
<span class="button-grid-action kendo-lexia-tooltip icon-archive" role="button" title="Archive Student">
<span>Archive Student</span>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to `select span with text - Edit Studen` try any of this:

```
//span[@title='Edit Student']/span
//span[text()='Edit Student']
```

If you want to select `Edit Studen with role="button"` try any of this:

```
//span[@title='Edit Student'][@role='button']
//span[@role='button'][./span[text()='Edit Student']]
//span[@role='button'][./span[.='Edit Student']]
```

Answer (score 5):

simply use can use any of this xpaths

```
//span[contains(text(),'Edit Student')]
//*[contains(text(),'Edit Student')]
//span [@class='button-grid-action kendo-lexia-tooltip icon-pencil']/span
//span [@title='Edit Student']/span
//span [contains(@title,'Edit Student')]/span
//span [contains(@class,'button-grid-action kendo-lexia-tooltip icon-pencil')]/span
```

Answer (score 4):

**To select the *outer* `span`, this XPath,**

```
//span[@role='button' and normalize-space()='Edit School']
```

will select `span` elements with a `button` `@role` and a normalized string value of `Edit School`.

**To select the *inner* `span`, this XPath,**

```
//span[text()='Edit School']
```

will select `span` elements with an immediate text node child whose value is `Edit School`.

You can, of course, further qualify the heritage in either case as needed.

### See also

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)

Answer (score 2):

This should get the span text

```
//span[.='Edit Student']
```