# XPath for a link given anchor text substring

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have this not so neat HTML piece:

```
<a href="#" onclick="JavaScript:fnActivity('-247239453','C');return false;">
    ACCOUNT
    -
    <span class="td-copy-nowrap">4575 <span class="td-copy-nowrap">6017785<span class="td-link-icon">›</span></span></span>
</a>
```

And I have this meta-information: `6017785`

Can I write a xpath selector that will find the link (`a`) element based on this number?

I tried `//span[contains(text(), '6017785')]/ancestor::a` but it doesn't seem to work, probably because of the span inside a span, near the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//a[contains(.,'6017785')]
```

will select all `a` elements whose string value contains the substring, `6017785`.

**See also:**

- **[Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath/34595441)**