# XPath for text is not working

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

[image: DOM]

I want to locate label by using its text property.

I tried

```
//label[normalize-space(text())='Only allow resources who are']
//label[contains(normalize-space(text()),'Only allow resources who are')]
```

But none of them work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//label[normalize-space()='Only allow resources who are']
```

will select all `label` elements whose space-normalized [***string value***](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) is the targeted text.

**See also**

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)

Comment: ty kjhughes. Final working Xpath. //label[normalize-space(.)='Only allow resources who are']

Comment: The `.` inside `normalize-space()` works but shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: got it. Thank you kjhughes.