# XPath to find text split over multiple descendants

Tags: xml, xpath, openxml

I have a OOXML (from a Word .docx file) that looks like this:

```
<w:tr>
    <w:tc>
        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>~TABLE_xxx~</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:tc>
</w:tr>
<w:tr>
    <w:tc>
        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>~TABLE_</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="00FB4DC5">
                <w:t>xxx</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>~</w:t>
            </w:r>
         </w:p>
     </w:tc>
</w:tr>
```

I want to find all  elements where the descendants text contains "**~TABLE_xxx~**".

I have tried the following:

```
//w:tr[descendant::text()[contains(., "~TABLE_xxx~")]]
```

However this only matches the first `<w:tr>` of my doc. My guess is that because the second one has text split in different `<w:r>` (Word "runs" of text), I don't get a match.

What is the way around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing *text nodes* is the wrong way to go, especially with OOXML, which frequently breaks strings into `w:r` runs.  Instead, test [**string-values**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value).

This XPath,

```
//w:tr[contains(.,"~TABLE_xxx~")]
```

will select all `w:tr` elements whose string-value contains the targeted string.

**See also:** ***[Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)***

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the references, helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Search by 'xxx' is not an option?

```
//w:tr[descendant::text()[contains(., "xxx")]]
```

Comment: Nope, I simplified here, but "xxx" here might be found elsewhere in the doc, and it shouldn't match.