# What is the difference between //*[*] and //*[.] in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to understand the difference between

```
//*[.] and //*[*]
```

These return different number of elements.

Also where I can use the **dot** instead of attribute

```
 //tag[@Attribute="value"]
```

Not just in case of text?  And what does the syntax look like?  Because I tried

```
//tag[@.="value"] and //tag[.="value"]
```

and the last one only worked in case of text but not instead of case

```
//tag[@id="value"]
```

for example, so when can I change the dot instead of attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`//*[.]` will select all elements.  It is equivalent to `//*`.

`//*[*]` will select all elements that have at least one child element.

`//tag[@.="value"]` is syntactically invalid.

`//tag[.="value"]` will select all `tag` elements whose [***string value***](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) equals `value`.  For example, for this XML,

```
<tag id="r">
  <tag id="a">value</tag>
  <tag id="b">val<br/>ue</tag>
  <tag id="c"><span>val</span><span>ue</span></tag>
  <tag id="f"> value</tag>
  <tag id="g">Value</tag>
</tag>
```

`//tag[.="value"]` will select

```
<tag id="a">value</tag>
<tag id="b">val<br/>ue</tag>
<tag id="c"><span>val</span><span>ue</span></tag>
```

See also [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath)