# XPath - Select All Text As Single Line

Tags: html, xml, xpath, web-scraping, xpath-1.0

I have the following HTML:

```
<p>
    Some cool text
    <a href="#">looks like</a>
    this.
</p>
```

I want to grab the text as a single line:

> Some cool text looks like this.

I'm currently using the following XPath query:

> //p//text()

And it returns all the text, but as separate lines:

> Some cool text
>
> looks like
>
> this.

Any thoughts on how to modify my query so it can return on a single line?

The query needs to meet XPath1.0 requirements.

Answer (score 2):

`text()` selects individual text nodes, and there will always be at least one text node in between elements (where there is text). What you want is to convert the `p` to a string:

```
//p/string(.)
```

Comment: Good, +1, but note that it requires XPath 2.0.

Comment: @kjhughes The question is tagged `xquery`, and XPath 2 is part of the XQuery 1 spec.

Comment: It's a bit surprising to see both [tag:xquery] and [tag:web-scraping] together, so a tagging mistake isn't inconceivable.  Anyway, later readers might benefit from an explicit note.

Comment: @kjhughes Yeah, I am also curious :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have XPath-2.0 or above available you can use `string-join(...)` to merge the `text()` values:

```
string-join(normalize-space(p))
```

Answer (score 2):

This XPath (1.0 on up),

```
string(normalize-space())
```

will return

```
"Some cool text looks like this."
```

in a single line, as requested.

See also [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)