# XPath's string-length() of a node without its children

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I need a one-line XPath 1.0 expression to calculate the length of a node, but excluding text in any child nodes (if they are present).

For instance, the string-length() of

```
<node>This is text</node>
```

is 12 (ok), but the string-length() of

```
<node>This is<any>any text</any> text</node>
<node>This <any>any text</any>is text</node>
```

is more than 12 (not ok).

I cannot use `string-length(//node/text())`, because it takes the first chunk of text inside `node`, if there are any child nodes inside `node`.

Comment: You would need XPath 2 `sum(text()/string-length())` or 3 `sum(text()!string-length())` to have a single, compact expression.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only 1.0 version in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

XPath 1.0 alone cannot provide a character count of only the text node children of an element.  You'll also have to use facilities of the language hosting the XPath library.

### XPath 2.0 and up

This XPath (first posted by @MartinHonnen [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54983894/xpaths-string-length-of-a-node-without-its-children/54984907#comment96725919_54983894)),

```
sum(/node/text()/string-length())
```

will provide a character count of all text node children of `/node`, as requested.

### **See also**

- The definition of [string value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) in XPath
- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)

Answer (score 0):

Use this hope will run for 1.0:

```
string-length(//node)
```

Comment: Nope, it counts text in child nodes.

Comment: You don't want to count child's text()? so what is the output you are excepting for below two nodes?

Comment: As for the first one, 12. If any child node is present, ignore its length.