# Xpath for span in svg

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Cannot find the xpath for span after svg. I need to get list of all elements and validate if the text is Account

I tried xpath

```
List<WebElement> listOffices = 
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div  [@id='joblist']//div[@id='view-   
content']//div[@id='page-data']//div[contains(@id,'project-tags')]/span/span/*[name()='svg']"));
```

The Dom elements are below :

```
    <div id="project-tags-119651" class="details uk-margin-remove-top" xpath="1">
        <span class="tag mute"> 
            <span uk-icon="icon:tag;ratio:0.8" class="uk-icon">
                <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ratio="0.8"> <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.1" d="M17.5,3.71 L17.5,7.72 C17.5,7.96 17.4,8.2 17.21,8.39 L8.39,17.2 C7.99,17.6 7.33,17.6 6.93,17.2 L2.8,13.07 C2.4,12.67 2.4,12.01 2.8,11.61 L11.61,2.8 C11.81,2.6 12.08,2.5 12.34,2.5 L16.19,2.5 C16.52,2.5 16.86,2.63 17.11,2.88 C17.35,3.11 17.48,3.4 17.5,3.71 L17.5,3.71 Z"></path> <circle cx="14" cy="6" r="1"></circle></svg>
            </span> 
            Account
        </span>
    </div>
```

I need xpath to :    Account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you should use

```
//span[@class='tag mute' and normalize-space(.)='Account']
```

Used `Class` on the safer side, but you have to use `normalize-space` to remove the preceding and following white spaces (spaces, tabs,new lines) while comparing the text as part of xpath.

Comment: By the way, `Account` span is not under `Svg` it's a text node of span with `tag mute` class.

Comment: I could get the text and it is working thanks , to learn i did not understand why does this xpath does not work to get text.                                       
    //span[@class='tag mute']/span or //span[@class='tag mute']/span/*

Comment: Updated the original post html for better understanding, now if you look at the html `Account` text is directly under span with tag mute class but not `span[]/span`

Comment: Good explanation, +1.   @BretA: See also [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)