# XPath - select element with inside text, even text of subelements

Tags: xpath

I have this `HTML`:

```
<div>
    I
    <span> need</span>
    this
    <span> text</span>
</div>
```

I want to find this `div`, looking at what text have inside (concatenate all text).

Something like: `//div[text() = 'I need this text']`, but of course, it not work.

How I can done this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-normalize-space)...

```xml
//div[normalize-space() = 'I need this text']
```

Comment: Good answer (+1).   See also [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085) for why OP's `text()`-based predicate failed.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is close; try this expression:

```
div[normalize-space(string-join(.//text(),''))='I need this text']
```

The expression first joins all the text nodes in the element, then strips spaces from the joined string and finally looks for an element (`div` in this case) which has the property that the normalized string of its text nodes is equal to the target string.

Comment: Good call using normalize-space() (we answered at the same time). You don't need the string-join() though; normalize-space defaults to using the string-value of the context node. Also, string-join() is only available in xpath 2.0+.

Comment: @DanielHaley - Yup; I realized this now after trying your solution; live and learn!

Answer (score 0):

this should help you

```
//div[. = 'I need this text']
```