# How to select a node which has an empty element in xml

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am looking to fetch a node which has an empty element.

below is my xml

```
<sys>
   <platform>
      <contact>
        <name>company</name>
        <LVN>test</LVN>
        <address></address>
        <phone>12345</phone>
        <pager/>
    </contact>
  </platform>
</sys>
```

I am using the below query
/sys/platform/contact[./address/text()='' and ./LVN/text()='test']

But it is not fetching anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** There is no text node child of the `address` element.

**Solution:** Test the *string value* of the `address` element rather than its (non-existent) text node child...

This XPath,

```
/sys/platform/contact[address='' and LVN='test']
```

will select those `contact` elements whose `address` string value is an empty string and whose `LVN` element has a string value of `test'`.

**See also**

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)