# How to test string broken across multiple elements?

Tags: html, css, xml, selenium, xpath

Can anyone help me out with a relative XPath expression that will verify a text that is contained inside multiple `span` elements

```
<div id="id1">
  <span >Hello </span>
  <span class="class2">World </span>
</div>`
```

I am new to selenium and I haven't used XPath that much. I need an XPath that will **return the text "Hello World"** in one line(preferred outcome) or even a list of text values.

Answer (score 3):

This XPath,

```
normalize-space(//div[@id="id1"])
```

will return the space-normalized, string-value of the first `div` with an `id` attribute value equal to `id1`,

```
Hello World
```

as requested.

### Notes

- Key concept is that of the [*string-value*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of an element.
- If you cannot be certain that there's only a single `div` element with `id="id1"`, or if you wish your XPath to work with 2.0+, explicitly select only the first one to pass to `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  normalize-space((//div[@id="id1"])[1])
  ```

### See also

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)

Comment: Brilliant answer! Never tried (or needed) to used normalize-space before but it works very well - one quick note is in selenium you use xpaths for element identification rather than returning text - wrap that with an assert and your in business:  `//div[normalize-space((//div[@id="id1"]))="Hello World"]`  - if you find that element, your text exists and assert would pass

Comment: @RichEdwards: Thank you for the compliment and the helpful Selenium addendum.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need an xpath here.

For the source you provided, you can use `.text` against the parent div and it returns the text.

This simple page:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="id1">
            <span >Hello </span>
            <span class="class2">World </span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(r"C:\Git\PythonSelenium\TextSplitOverTags.html")

print(driver.find_element_by_id('id1').text)
```

output looks like in the console...

[image: getting text from selenium]

When you get the output you can verify the text is as expected.