# Unable to fetch the element based on the string value of the descendant text nodes

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I am trying to locate the element div based on its descendant text nodes.

**Below is the HTML:**

```
<html><head></head><body>

<div>
<div class="d x">Foo</div>
<span>Mumbai</span>
<h1>DEF</h1>
</div>

</body></html>
```

**Selenium code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[.='FooMumbaiDEF']"));
```

As per my understanding and after referring to the stackoverflow posts,
[Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath)
the string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order.

But I am getting `NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //div[.='FooMumbaiDEF']`

Any idea why it is not able to find an element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run the `$x("//div/descendant::text()")` to check all the descendant text nodes of the `div` element. It showed seven descendant text nodes. So, it contained four text nodes having data as `\n` i.e. new-line character along with the above 3 text nodes i.e. `Foo`, `Mumbai` and `DEF`.
So, the Xpath expression to select the above `div` node should be:

```
$x("//div[.='\nFoo\nMumbai\nDEF\n']")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below xpath because the one you have used is not correct.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'FooMumbaiDEF')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`//div[.='FooMumbaiDEF']` is not valid XPath if you want to deal with web element based on its text then you can use **contains()** function within Xpath expression which is used to search for the web elements that contain a particular text.

Try below xpath to handle Foo text from your webpage :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Foo')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="d x">Foo</div>
            <span>Mumbai</span>
            <h1>DEF</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

there is no descendant text nodes as such. But there are descendant `<div>`, `<span>` and `<h1>` nodes with *text*.

---

### Solution

To identify the parent `<div>` element with respect to the text within the descendant `<div>`, `<span>` and `<h1>` nodes you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using the descendant `<div>`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[./div[text()='Foo']]"));
  ```
- Using the descendant `<div>`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[./span[text()='Mumbai']]"));
  ```
- Using the descendant `<div>`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[./h1[text()='DEF']]"));
  ```

Ideally, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the  `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following *locator strategies*:

- Using the descendant `<div>`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[./div[text()='Foo']]")))
  ```
- Using the descendant `<div>`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[./span[text()='Mumbai']]")))
  ```
- Using the descendant `<div>`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[./h1[text()='DEF']]")))
  ```

Comment: The `div` element does have descendant text nodes, just ran the `$x("/descendant-or-self::node()/div//text()")`, it returned 7 descendant text nodes...