# XPath following/preceding limited to element descendents?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Let's imagine the following structure :

```
<div class="text">
  plainjkhtext-identifsdficccccator-123
  <img src="#" />

  PLAINTEXT-identificator-123
  <img src="1" /> 

  </div>

<div>
  <img src="2" /> 
  <img src="1" /> 
</div>
```

And this XPath:

```
//div[@class, "text"]/text()[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'plaintext-identificator-123')]/following-sibling::img[position()<3]
```

Basically, this gets two `<img>` elements after `"plaintext-identificator-123"` text.

I need to get the `<img>` elements even if they don't have the same parent.

```
<div class="text">
  plainjkhtext-identifsdficccccator-123
  <img src="#" />

  PLAINTEXT-identificator-123
  <b><img src="1" /></b>

  </div>

<div>
  <img src="2" /> 
  <img src="1" /> 
</div>
```

I cannot use "following" axis though because that would get the `<img>` element from the second `<div>`, which doesn't even have the "text" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//img[ancestor-or-self::*/preceding-sibling::node()
       [translate(normalize-space(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') 
         = 'plaintext-identificator-123']
       [ancestor::div/@class="text"]]
```

will limit `img` elements selected to those following the targeted text *within the targeted* `div`, even if the targeted text is within its own markup, as requested.

In XPath 2.0, use [`lower-case()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-lower-case) rather than `translate()`, or match the text with the case-insensitive `i` flag of [`matches()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches).

Comment: Works just right. And if the plaintext-identificator-123 must be in the same <div>?

Comment: Answer updated to ensure that the targeted `text()` node is also within the targeted `div.`

Comment: Thank you! This will only select the <img> elements from the <div@text> where the plaintext-identificator-123 is present, am i right? So if there will be more div@text classes with the identificator it won't cause problems.

Comment: The text must be preceding-sibling, however it can be surrounded by for example <b> tag. The preceding-sibling is not working with that.

Comment: Wow, ok, so instead of testing for preceding text node siblings, check for preceding sibling nodes of any type whose string value equals the targeted text.

Comment: */preceding-sibling::*/text()

Comment: I used `node()` rather than `*` so as to still capture the original text-as-sibling option too.

Comment: But that's only one step. If the text was in <b><i> for example, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Actually it should work fine for any depth of surrounding elements because such surrounding doesn't change the ancestor's [***string value***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085).  Try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221709/discussion-between-tadeas-jilek-and-kjhughes).