# Xpath equals OR contains text

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to do an or between = and contains. I know how to do or between multiple contains but not multiple equals. I want to do something like this but it's not working:

```
xpath=//*[text()[="HOA fees" or [contains(.,"HOA fee:")]]]/following-sibling::*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your syntax problem, change

```
//*[text()[="HOA fees" or [contains(.,"HOA fee:")]]]/following-sibling::*
```

to

```
//*[text()[.="HOA fees" or contains(.,"HOA fee:")]]/following-sibling::*
```

This will select all sibling elements following all elements with a text node child that equals `HOA fees` or has a `HOA fee:` substring.  If that's not exactly what you had in mind, follow-up in comments to clarify your actual goal.

**See also:**

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)