# XPath 'contains()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence)

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

Given the XML:

```
<Dial>
    <DialID>
        24521
    </DialID>
    <DialName>
        Base Price
    </DialName>
</Dial>
<Dial>
    <DialID>
        24528
    </DialID>
    <DialName>
        Rush Options
    </DialName>
    <DialValue>
        1.5
    </DialValue>
</Dial>
<Dial>
    <DialID>
        24530
    </DialID>
    <DialName>
        Bill Rush Charges
    </DialName>
    <DialValue>
        School
    </DialValue>
</Dial>
```

I can use the contains() function in my xpath:

```
//Dial[DialName[contains(text(), 'Bill')]]/DialValue
```

To retrieve the values I'm after:

```
School
```

The above XML is stored in a field in my SQL database so I'm using the .value method to select from that field.

```
SELECT Dials.DialDetail.value('(//Dial[DialName[contains(text(), "Bill")]]/DialValue)[1]','VARCHAR(64)') AS BillTo
FROM CampaignDials Dials
```

I can't seem to get the syntax right though... the xpath works as expected (tested in Oxygen and elsewhere) but when I use it in the XQuery argument of the .value() method, I get an error:

```
Started executing query at Line 1
Msg 2389, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
XQuery [Dials.DialDetail.value()]: 'contains()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
Total execution time: 00:00:00.004
```

I've tried different variations of single and double quotes with no effect. The error refers to an XPath data type for attributes, but I'm not retrieving an attribute; I'm getting the text value. I receive the same error if I type the response with //Dial[DialName[contains(text(), 'Bill')]]/DialValue/text() instead.

What is the correct way to use `contains()` in an XQuery when it's used in the `XML.value()` method? Or is this the wrong approach to begin with?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly have it right, you just need `[1]` on the `text()` function to guarantee a single value.

You should also use `text()` on the actual node you are pulling out, for performance reasons.

Also, `//` can be inefficient, so only use it if you really need recursive descent. You can instead use `/*/` to get the first node of any name.

```sql
SELECT
    Dials.DialDetail.value(
        '(//Dial[DialName[contains(text()[1], "Bill")]]/DialValue/text())[1]',
        'VARCHAR(64)') AS BillTo
FROM CampaignDials Dials
```

As Yitzhak Kabinsky notes, this only gets you one value per row of the table, you need `.nodes` if you want to shred the XML itself into rows.

Comment: This solved it. Thank you. In this case I'm certain there can't be more than one DialName so I didn't think to force it to only get the first.

Comment: Yes it must be statically guaranteed to only have one result. Same issue with `.value`

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your actual database case that fails and your reduced sample case that works is likely one of different data.

The error,

> `contains()` requires a singleton (or empty sequence)

indicates that one of your `DialName` elements has multiple text node children rather than a single text node child as you're expecting.

You can abstract away such variations by testing the [*string-value*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of `DialName` rather than its text node children:

```
//Dial[contains(DialName, 'Bill')]/DialValue
```

### See also

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've changed the statement to: Dials.DialDetail.value('(//dial[contains(dialname, "Bill")]/dialvalue)[1]','VARCHAR(64)') AS BillTo

The error remains. (You'll notice I fixed some XML syntax problems as well)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do XML shredding in MS SQL Server correctly.

You need to apply filter in the XQuery `.nodes()` method.
The `.value()` method is just for the actual value retrieval.
It is possible to pass SQL Server variable as a parameter instead of the hard-coding "Bill" value.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, DialDetail XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (DialDetail) VALUES
(N'<Dial>
        <DialID>24521</DialID>
        <DialName>Base Price</DialName>
    </Dial>
    <Dial>
        <DialID>24528</DialID>
        <DialName>Rush Options</DialName>
        <DialValue>1.5</DialValue>
    </Dial>
    <Dial>
        <DialID>24530</DialID>
        <DialName>Bill Rush Charges</DialName>
        <DialValue>School</DialValue>
    </Dial>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , c.value('(DialID/text())[1]', 'INT') AS DialID
    , c.value('(DialName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS DialName
    , c.value('(DialValue/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS DialValue
FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY DialDetail.nodes('/Dial[contains((DialName/text())[1], "Bill")]') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID | DialID |     DialName      | DialValue |
+----+--------+-------------------+-----------+
|  1 |  24530 | Bill Rush Charges | School    |
+----+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```