# Find element in xml-tree

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml.etree

I want to find in a XML file only the tree with for example `code = "7041"`.
Here is a part of the XML file:

```
<lens>
    <code>7041</code>
    <names>
        <name language="en">
            <long>synchrony SV Curves HDC 1.5 PH Brn</long>
        </name>

</lens>
```

Here is my code:

---

```
   for elem in tree.findall('lenses/lens/code/[@text="7041"]'):
        print (elem.tag, elem.text)
```

This code does not work, I do not find `"7041"`. What is wrong?
How can I select only the part in the file were `code="7041"`?

Answer (score 2):

`@` is for attributes; for a text node test, use `text()`,

```
//lens/code/[@text()="7041"]
             ^
```

and also remove the spurious `/` ahead of the predicate:

```
//lens/code/[text()="7041"]
           ^
```

to get this XPath expression,

```
//lens/code[text()="7041"]
```

will select all of the `code` element children of `lens` elements, provided the `code` element has a `text()` text node child with a string value of `"7041"`.

You could also test the string value of `code`,

```
//lens/code[.="7041"]
```

If you actually want to select `lens` elements, elevate the predicate:

```
//lens[code="7041"]
```

### See also

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)

<sub>Thanks to Mads Hansen for correcting a glaring mistake in a previous version of this answer.</sub>