# XPath SyntaxError: invalid predicate with text()

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xpath, elementtree

What am I doing wrong?

When using what I believe to be a valid XPath expression in Python, I get

> SyntaxError: invalid predicate

My code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data = '''<root>
            <child>
                <p>aaa</p>
                <p>bbb</p>
            </child>
        </root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(data)

p_element = root.findall(".//p[text()='aaa']")

print(p_element[0].text)
```

Running this code produces an invalid predicate error, but I believe it is correct.  I'm using Python version 3.10.0, and running this on Windows.

It seems to have something to do with the `text()` part of the XPath; with that removed, it does not error.

Comment: Try `"//p[contains(., 'aaa')]"`

Comment: `//p[. = 'aaa']` could work.OP's is indeed and invalid expression on ElementTree module: see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.//p[text()='aaa']` is a perfectly valid XPath expression.

The problem is that [ElementTree's implementation of XPath is incomplete](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support).

For your XML, testing the string value, `.//p[.='aaa']`, would be a work-around if you're stuck with `ElementTree`.  Better would be to only use an XPath library such as [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/) that better follows the standard.

### See also

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)