# Selecting Single Node in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

my XML is single like

```
<linkToFooterRepository>1054</linkToFooterRepository>
<linkToTopNavRepository>1188</linkToTopNavRepository>
<author>1413</author>
```

and then i have

```
var xmlListItems = xPathNavigator.Select(xPathChildren)
            .Cast<XPathNavigator>()
            .OrderByDescending(x =>
            {
                var xmlNode = x.SelectSingleNode("author=1413");


            })
            .Skip(pager.CurrentPageIndex * pager.PageSize)
            .Take(pager.PageSize);
```

I keep getting a Expression must evaluate to a node set error. I'm pretty new to Xpath so I think something with how I pass author is getting this error. In time I plan on making the author ID (1413) into a variable to use with many authors.

thanks

Comment: Can you post more of the file, the initial lines, on the start of the XML?

Comment: How are you getting your `x` variable?

Comment: Your syntax is off. The XPath should be `"author[text()='1413']"` See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3206975/215552.

Comment: Thank you Mike, my syntax was indeed off

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (assuming you have a root element):

```
var xmlNode = x.SelectSingleNode(@"/root/author[text()=1413]");
```

I created this simple code, because your XML does not contain a root element.

```
var xml =
          "<root>" +
          "    <linkToFooterRepository>1054</linkToFooterRepository>" +
          "    <linkToTopNavRepository>1188</linkToTopNavRepository>" +
          "    <author>1413</author>" 
          "</root>"
          ;

var x = new XmlDocument();
x.LoadXml(xml);

var xmlNode = x.SelectSingleNode(@"/root/author[text()='1413']");  // /author=[1413]
```