# Robot framework select variable from dropdown

Tags: xpath, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am trying to select an item from a dropdown list in robot framework (using RIDE), but I cannot get the item by variable name.

```
<div class="chosen-drop">
    <div class="chosen-search">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <ul class="chosen-results">
        <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0">Geen optie gekozen</li>
        <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">ABB</li>
        <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">Algem</li>
        <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">AOV</li>
        <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5">AW</li>
        <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="8">AOZ</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can use this and get the result:

```
Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="KEUZE_N_MiddelId_N1010D_chosen"]
Click Element    xpath=//*

[@id="KEUZE_N_MiddelId_N1010D_chosen"]/div/ul/li[4]
```

But the index number can change, so I want to click the element based on the value, in this example 'ABB'. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried [Select from list](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20From%20List)?

Comment: Try Select From List By Label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try the following:

Select From List By Label| css=ul.chosen-results| ABB

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206975/xpath-selecting-elements-that-equal-a-value) but not exact enough to be considered a duplicate. Based on your already achieved results I think this should work for you.

`[@id="KEUZE_N_MiddelId_N1010D_chosen"]/div/ul/li[text() = 'ABB']`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the problem is that the id can change every deploy and we dont have control of it. we have controle over the tekst in active-result